# Removing Android Wear 1.x support on your application update

Tags: android, wear-os

We have an Android app that is already on the Google Play Store that packages the Wear APK to support the Wear 1.x devices. We want to remove support for Wear and plan not to package the Wear APK in the next release. What happens to existing users who were using the Wear app? Does it get deleted automatically without any warning? Are users given a choice not to update if the wear app will be deleted or be broken? I cannot find a documentation on this and would like to understand the user impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you distribute a handheld APK without the embedded (Wear 1.x) APK, the Wear system will uninstall the watch app from any of your existing users' Wear 1.x devices who upgrade to it. No warning or confirmation will be issued.

It's easy enough to test this yourself (which is what I just did):

1. Install your current production APK (with embedded Wear APK) on a phone.
2. The system will push the embedded APK to the watch, as normal.
3. Generate another production-signed phone APK without the embedded APK (e.g., comment the `wearApp` line out of your build.gradle).
4. Install this APK to the phone.
5. Observe that the watch app gets uninstalled.

Installing signed APKs works exactly the same whether they come from adb or the Play store.

Comment: Thanks for checking.
Somehow I missed it before but I did find some documentation on this at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps.html.
`Caution: If you
publish an update to your existing, production phone APK
that has removed an embedded Wear APK, production users who update the phone APK before installing your standalone Wear APK will lose their existing Wear app and its data.
If you publish an update to your existing, production phone APK, continue to embed your watch APK into that phone APK.`

Comment: To me that doc seems to be speaking about Wear 2 users (on 1.x there's no  possibility of "installing your standalone Wear APK"), so it's unclear whether the same situation holds on 1.x. But now we know, it does.